# How do I automate a swipe from bottom to top of an iOS app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to automating gestures with Xcode - I would like to automate simple swipe gesture from the bottom of the screen to the top, so a can have a repeatable gesture to profile.

I am trying to follow this example, but the gesture is more than I need: https://jrwilliamsios438.medium.com/automated-ui-testing-in-swift-ios-46e1c9993316

How do I automate a swipe from bottom to top of an iOS app in Xcode?